# Does a natural 20 on an attack roll still crit if it was forced to be rerolled?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, critical-hit, attack-roll

Does a natural 20 on an attack roll still crit if it was forced to be rerolled?

Say a creature attacks me, and gets a nat. 20 on the attack roll (which would be a critical hit). However, I use the *Silvery Barbs* spell or the Lucky feat to make the creature reroll the attack roll; this reroll would still hit, but the die roll isn't a natural 20. Is the attack still a critical hit? Or does this cancel the crit damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
If a reroll is forced, unless specified otherwise, you must always use the second roll (in general; I can't find an overall rule in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* about rerolling, but every ability which allows or forces a reroll that I can find specifies which roll to use, and most say you must use the second).

Both of the abilities you point out divert from the general case. The [*silvery barbs*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silvery-barbs) spell specifies the following (*Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos*, page 38; emphasis mine):

> You magically distract the triggering creature and turn its momentary uncertainty into encouragement for another creature. The triggering creature must reroll the d20 and **use the lower roll**.

So in the case of *Silvery Barbs*, you must use the lowest roll, so even if the first roll was a hit and the *second* roll was a crit, you'd still need to use the first non-crit roll.

The description of the [Lucky](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/lucky) feat says (*Player's Handbook*, page 167; emphasis mine):

> You can choose to spend one of your luck points after you roll the die, but before the outcome is determined. **You choose which of the d20s is used for the attack roll, ability check, or saving throw.**

You get to choose which roll is used, and I don't know why you'd ever choose the one which results in a crit against you.

The crit only exists for the natural 20 roll; it does not persist for any rerolls, even for the same attack.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add crit damage part on my post. I'm wondering if the crit damage rolls still go through if its crit attack rolls got changed to a non crit.

Comment: @NilNox If it is not a critical hit, there is no extra damage associated with the critical hit, because there is no critical hit.

Comment: I think this is correct, but it needs some evidence to back it up. Can you quote the relevant sections from the rules?

Comment: Interestingly, I actually can't find anywhere in the Dungeon Masters Guide that specifies you must use the second roll when a reroll occurs, but every single ability I look at which causes a reroll specifies which roll to use, and most of them say you must use the second roll.

Comment: @Turksarama: I don't think there's a general rule that covers which roll must be used, which is why it's specified each time a feature says to reroll something. Sometimes the second roll must be used no matter what (e.g. the fighter's Indomitable feature); sometimes the higher/lower roll must be used (e.g. advantage/disadvantage); and sometimes you can choose which roll to use (e.g. the Lucky feat).